# How to grab options in child list for subset of selections in parent list, using BeautifulSoup & Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful soup to scrape an HTML page that contains two HTML select lists of 'prefixes' and 'suffixes'. The second list (suffixes) displays only when the user selects an option from the "parent" prefixes select list. The options displayed in the suffix select list change with each selection in the prefix list.

I am grabbing a subset of specific prefixes, and I want to grab the text for each suffix option for that subset of prefixes.

The Python:

```
prefixSubset = ['A', 'B', 'C']
url = 'http:myUrl.com'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
scrapedPrefixesSubset = soup.findAll(value = prefixSubset)

# Now I want to iterate over scrapedPrefixSubset and get the text for all
# suffix options, which change for each option selected in the prefix list
```

The HTML with 'B' selected in the parent list:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="prefixes" onchange="javascript:updatePrefixes()">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B" selected="selected">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    <option value="E">E</option>
                    <option value="F">F</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td>
                <select id="suffixes" onchange="javascript:updateSuffixes()">
                    <option value="24569">400</option>
                    <option value="15867">500</option>
                    <option value="97463">600</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Could you either show the HTML representation of the both lists, or share a link to the target website? Would really help to help. Thanks.

Comment: The extract you've added is insufficient to help, because the javascript behind all this could be doing a lot (DOM injection?). Either link to the real website or provide more info.